# Win Batch: Help defining variable in a FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I made this script that finds all directories and echoes the directorie's name to a `.txt` file. The script is working but it ends up echoing only `%A` without any value. My script is below!

```
set /a count=0
setlocal EnableDelayedExtensions
FOR /D %%A in ("*") DO (call :sub)
endlocal
pause
exit

:sub
(echo [DIR] %%A)>>%count%.txt
set /a count+=1
```

The output in the `.txt` files is `[DIR] %A`.
Any idea how to fixe this? Thanks -David

Answer (score 1):

First remark, you are using an invalid option for `setlocal` but that is probably just a typo.
The problem is that you are try to use a for-parameter where it cannot be used.
The rule is "A for-parameter can only be used within the command or command block () of a for loop"
Your subroutine is not within the command block of a for loop, but you can start a dummy for loop in the subroutine which will give you access to all available for-parameters.

```
set /a count=0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /D %%A in ("*") DO (call :sub)
endlocal
pause
exit/b

:sub
For %%. in (.) do (echo [DIR] %%A)>>%count%.txt
set /a count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter to the subroutine.

From https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1154761&seqNum=11 :

```
for %%f in (*.dat) do call :onefile %%f
exit /b

:onefile
echo Processing file %1...
echo ... commands go here ...
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've already enabled delayed expansion, there's no need to use a `Call` to a label, just do it within the loop.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "count=0"
For /D %%G In (*) Do (
    Set /A count += 1
    (Echo [DIR] %%G) 1>"!count!.txt"
)
```

On this version, I've started at `1` instead of `0` for the first text file name, if you really want to start at `0`, change line `3` to `Set "count=-1"`